# Forwarding Messages with Microsoft Teams Bot

Tags: bots, botframework, ms-office, microsoft-teams

So I'm trying to create a chatbot in MS Teams with the Microsoft Bot Framework in order for a handful of end-users to be able to do basic troubleshooting. Does anyone know of a good way to be able for the Bot to be able forward certain questions that do not have responses within the knowledge base? Does anyone have any suggestions on what would be the best way of doing this? I've looked briefly into MS Flow. Thanks!!!

EDIT: So In order to further clarify what I am trying to do I'm adding some more. When someone asks a question to the Q&A Bot in Microsoft Teams. If the bot *doesn't* have an answer, the question will then be forwarded to a live agent that could answer the question asked in real-time. I'm looking for some type of software or API that could do the forwarding part

Comment: Are you trying to forward the control to a real agent when the bot does not have an answer? Could you please elaborate more on your query?

Comment: Yeah! any question that the bot would not a have an answer for, would be forwarded to a live agent via email or some other type of connector.

Comment: Please try [deeplinking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/deep-links#generating-a-deep-link-to-a-chat) to users's chat. This will redirect from bot to a real agent.

Comment: This teams app template is similar to what you're trying to accomplish: https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-faqplusplus-app

Answer (score 1):

@G-Snider you're in danger of having your question shut down if you don't provide more detail--like some code that you've tried, for example.

And I'm afraid I don't very clearly understand your question...however I'll take a stab at helping.

---

You could always use Dispatch connected to a QnA Maker knowledge base to determine if a user hits an intent that would be answer able to your QnA KB or if it's "None" intent--or if you don't want the LUIS layer.

- BF Dispatch Sample: [C#](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/14.nlp-with-dispatch) / [JS](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/javascript_nodejs/14.nlp-with-dispatch)

Alternatively, you could forego the Dispatch layer and stick with only QnA and work with [confidence scores and thresholds](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/blob/master/libraries/Microsoft.Bot.Builder.AI.QnA/QnAMakerOptions.cs#L26) that get returned that's built into the QnA module itself.

- QnA Maker Sample: [C#](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/11.qnamaker) / [JS](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/javascript_nodejs/11.qnamaker)

---

Second step, if your bot determines that the user hit `None` intent or has no result from your QnA KB directly, then you could implement human hand-off.

- [Human Hand-Off Sample](https://github.com/tompaana/intermediator-bot-sample)